# external CSS fails

Tags: html, css, http, external

Sometimes on completely valid browsers, but a hindered Internet connection, the webpage loads without some of the external css files, resulting in a ugly webpage.
Is there a way to prevent this without resorting to embedding all of the css in the html?

Comment: Just thinking some weird option to consider: Give `body` an inline style of `display: none` and at the end of the external css give body `display: block`. If the CSS is not loaded the body won't display and the website is not "ugly". Don't know whether this matches your requirements though. :)

Comment: If the problem is purely on the user's end, the solution is that they keep refreshing till it works. And make sure you have the correct caching headers so that they don't have to download all assets again on each refresh.

Comment: @Bazzz I wish it was that easy :) @thirtydot after 3 refreshes it becomes tiresome, what I want to know is if there is some way to FORCE the CSS file to load or what headers might be causing problems for low quality connections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you might be hitting the timeout when hitting the CSS file. You might try caching the CSS file on the client side by using far future headers. And minify the CSS so it has a small file size and can be quickly grabbed.

Comment: What if the CSS file isn't downloaded in the first place. It's these darn iPad's and their cheap replicas that suffer from this on low quality G3 connections.

Comment: If you can replicate the problem then you're halfway there :) If it's sporadic, then a solution would be to maybe breaking up the CSS file. If all else fails, try having part of the CSS in the HTML itself to see whether it's a rendering issue

Comment: CSS embedded in the HTML works fine, would it be sporadic if it happens 99% of the time? I will try splitting files, but I predict not having any file load at all, maybe it can only accept one http request at a time and thats used up already by 1 script file and cancels all requests?

Comment: It should definitely not be doing that. Have you put any `media` or `screen-size` attributes?

Comment: @JohnP yes I have, I use this one `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0;maximum-scale=1.0;" />`

Comment: Ah no, I meant on the `<link>` tag for the CSS. The meta should be fine.

Comment: @JohnP yeah thats what I thought too. The CSS link has nothing special in it `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />`

Answer (score 1):

Try to use less css files as much as possible because ever single css files send different http request so, when there are less css files that means less http request .Which automatically increase the speed & minify the css also .

Comment: there is only 1, and it's very small

Answer (score 0):

A general rule of performance is to reduce the number of HTTP transactions.  This is particularly important in these days of add-ins.  Each HTTP transaction adds an overhead of about 1kB up and down by adding the headers.  It adds load on the server and delays rendering.  It also opens up the risk of network timeouts -- especially a problem on 3G phone networks.

Regarding CSS,  it's better to have a single larger file than lots of smaller ones to avoid exactly the problems you're experiencing.  If you minify the file -- but don't optimise it -- it will also get rid of the comments and white space.

Similarly it's worth combining jQuery addins into a single file for the same reasons.